# How do i insert an image inside an input tag

Tags: html, css

i just want to show an image inside the input tag as like most of the awesome website do

[image: my code gives output like this...]

in this i want to insert an image inside the text-box before the register number and the password..How do i do it?

Comment: input { background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat scroll top left; }

Comment: there's two ways to do it,
1. use `background-image` proeprty
2. use img as `<img src=".." />` and use `position` property.

I'll prefer 2nd option as sometimes bg-image gets hidden.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the HTML for the text box:

```
<input type="text" name="whatever" id="funkystyling" />
```

Here's the CSS for the image on the left:

```
#funkystyling {

    background: white url(/path/to/icon.png) left no-repeat;
    padding-left: 17px;
}
```

And here's the CSS for the image on the right:

```
#funkystyling {
    background: white url(/path/to/icon.png) right no-repeat;
    padding-right: 17px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you are trying to have an icon infront of you input elements. You can use that by adding `<i>` tag infront of your input and style accordingly.

**HTML**

```
<div class="inner-addon left-addon">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicons-lock"></i>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* enable absolute positioning */

.inner-addon { 
    position: relative; 
    margin: 10px;
}

/* style icon */
.inner-addon .glyphicon {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* align icon */
.left-addon .glyphicon  { left:  0px;}
.right-addon .glyphicon { right: 0px;}

/* add padding  */
.left-addon input  { padding-left:  30px; }
.right-addon input { padding-right: 30px; }
```

Here is a working **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t3rf9r1z/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

I think something of this line can resolve your issue. Thus creating a div to look like a text box and hiding the border of the real text box

HTML

```
<div id="funkystyling">
<div></div>
<input type="text" name="whatever">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#funkystyling {
border:solid;
width: 300px
}

#funkystyling div{
border: solid 2px;
width: 20%;
height: 20px;
background: white url(/path/to/icon.png) left no-repeat;
float: left
}

#funkystyling-child input{
float: left;
width: 80%;
border: none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First option is to set background-image of input box, but the problem is you have to handle it for different input sizes .
The other option is to set pseudo elements before/after with the input box and specify the image url in content of pseudo elements.

In my opinion second option is more stable for your requirement.